# Shouldn't the "new" banner be removed from the "blog" link?

Tags: support, blog

On all the SE pages, the blog link is marked with the "new" banner.

[image: screenshot]

The blog is active for quite a long now, and I don't think it deserves the "new" banner anymore.

**EDIT**
Thanks to the notes here, I realize that "new" means that there are new entries and not that the blog itself is new. Well, at least for me this distinction wasn't clear without additional clarification. Maybe changing this to count of entries in the past 24 hours will be more intuitive.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The most recent blog post was only yesterday. I think if you click through to it the 'new' label goes away. (at least it has for me)

Comment: try hovering your mouse over the word "new"

Comment: Jeff, The point that  "new" relates to new blog entries is now clear, however it is not intuitive and as such may be improved. On the other hand, I really don't know much about user interfaces

Comment: @Jeff, why are blog posts not just in my drop down "in box" like all othew items of interest?

Comment: @ian that is for replies to you only. A blog entry is not a reply to you.

Answer (score 8):

The "new" only appears for 24 hours after a new blog entry has been posted. So if it displays "new" then there's a new blog post less than 24 hours old.

The "new" will disappear:

1. When you click on the blog link to read the post.
2. If you click on the "new" itself (though the blog link will remain for 24 hours).

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Since it's always there, I'm not even noticing it anymore, which I guess defeats the point of a "New" alert.

Comment: It isn't always there. Once you've read the new blog post, it disappears now. It took a feature request or two for this to be implemented, but it's working fine now and I see nothing wrong with the behavior. The idea is to annoy (alert?) people into reading the new blog posts. No one really knew about them before.

Comment: @Cody Gray, then it's not fully working yet. I just clicked on the "Blog" link an hour ago and I'm still seeing the New alert.

Comment: Did you refresh the page? I did it 5 minutes ago, and everything works just fine.... It may not sync across all sites on the network, though. I've only done it on Meta.

Comment: You must be looking at a different blog than I am. There was [an entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) posted today/yesterday. It's a very colorful rant likening subjective questions about programming languages to nonsense questions about fights between incongruous animal species. I quite liked it.

Comment: Yes, I just tried refreshing the page and the alert is still there. I have also tried clicking on the New label. When I do that, it goes away, but when I reload the page, it's back.

Comment: Do you have Javascript or cookies or something disabled on your browser? That's really weird that it doesn't work for you, because it works just fine for me.

Comment: Ok it's gone now. I'm not sure why it kept reappearing earlier today. When I was clicking on the link I definitely could see the "New" tag fading out, but when I was opening the page again it was back. Anyway, it's working fine now.